# Adding a divider in pinput package

Tags: flutter

[image: This what i want to achieve][image: pinput image]

I'm using pinput package in flutter and I want to add a divider in the middle of the textfields. How can I do that?
The first image is what I'm trying to achieve using pinput package.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can use the `Divider()` widget for a horizontal divider or `VerticalDivider()` for a vertical divider.

Comment: By divider do you mean an underline for the text?

Comment: Not to underline the text. After the first three text fields, there should be a divder then, the last three textfields comes after

Answer (score -1):

You can add them in a row with length of pin as 3, then use TextInputAction.next  when the controller length is 3. else you can create a custom input field following https://youtu.be/G9VDqDAA3ME

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. Please do include part of the related code as well as  it provide more context to the question. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer on how to answer a question on stackoverflow.